# Where did the term "flame war"/"flaming" come from?

Tags: meaning, terminology, phrase-origin, internet

I found this term on the history of [Tanenbaum and Torvalds debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanenbaum%E2%80%93Torvalds_debate), but I couldn't find the origin of the term.

I've understood the meaning (from UrbanDictionary):

> A flame war is a heated argument between two individuals, that results
>   in those involved posting personal attacks on each other during or
>   instead of debating the topic at hand.

So, what is the origin?

Comment: For old hackerese like this, the best place to turn for early documentation is the Jargon File, here’s its entry on *flame* in the online debate sense: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/flame.html

Comment: @DanBron Nice source! I'd accept this as answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**to flame** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/71018?rskey=1Acz0j&result=3#eid4320099) figurative

> b. Of persons: To burn (with envy, fury, indignation, etc.); to look
>   angrily or passionately upon. to flame out, up: **to break out into
>   open anger or indignation**; to ‘fire up’.

As in:

> 1548   N. Udall et al. tr. Erasmus Paraphr. Newe Test. I. Matt. xxii.
>   f.    'Whiche wholy flame with enuy and hatred'.

and

> 1681   J. Crowne Henry VI i. iv. 49   I flame with fury to be at it.

More recently:

intr. slang (orig. and chiefly Computing). To rant, argue, or harangue, esp. via an electronic medium (such as e-mail or postings to a newsgroup); to send an inflammatory, abusive, or (esp. in early use) inconsequential e-mail or posting, usually as a hasty response or in a rapid, angry exchange. Also trans.: to send (a person) such a message. Cf. flame n. and adj.

as in:

> 1981   CoEvolution Q. Spring 31/1   Flame, to speak incessantly and/or
>   rabidly on some relatively uninteresting subject or with a patently
>   ridiculous attitude.